# how is https post works and how is php can get the https post variable

Tags: php, https

Just wandering, how is https works? Also how is php able to get the https post? Is it just works like the normal get post in php??

Exmaple:
If there have a system having a https post to a websiet test.php , can I just get the post by using $_POST under test.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the decryption is done by the server's ssl layer automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Php doesn't handle the HTTP bs HTTPS. apache does. PHP behaves the same. So to answer your question - yes

Comment: apache … or any other webserver :)

Comment: @Kissaki - i was stereotyping :) Apache is the most popular webserver to run php, so I was assuming.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. :) Still, I just had to add that. :P

Answer (score 0):

Once your server is set up to handle https it's pretty much transparent to apps running on your server. Everything works the same way as HTTP, except the URL scheme and port will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make questions more clear in the future, reading them yourself again.

For information on HTTPS, why not check wikipedia (or any other source) first?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS

HTTPS encrypts the communication between client and server.
Abstract that away and you still have HTTP. Thus, PHP will not even know it was HTTPS that was communicated over (other than protocol, url etc it may ask/check for. but nothing you need to keep in mind when working with it)

So yes, $_POST works with HTTPS just like with HTTP.